# Jib crane Has Different Space

Tags: anylogic

Different spaces what does it mean?

This model will move input source material to different nodes.

The agent 1 and the crane com.anylogic.engine.markup.JibCrane@2ffe5f00 have different spaces

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the agents you push through the "moveByCrane" block are of type "Material Item". You can set that in the agent properties:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin. I have set the Main-Agent type and Agent type to Material Item. Still same error occurs. root.moveByCrane: 
The agent 1 and the crane com.anylogic.engine.markup.JibCrane@706f6179 have different spaces.  I think it is something to do with dimension???

Answer (score 0):

Select location of arrival and node for the source. Model working perfectly.

[image]

Comment: yes, you must force them into the actual network with this. Read moe about space and networks in the help to understand the concepts for this. And follow the tutorial on material-handling, it explains it well.